# How to deal with finding pattern in functions

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a polynomial such that $\forall x$; 
$f(x^2 + 2) = x^4 + 10x^2 + 4$

How would I go about finding a pattern for this?  I know that $(x^2 + 2) ^2 = x^4 + 4x^2 + 4$ but that doesn't help much

Comment: What you know, isn't so --- you meant to square the left side.

Comment: @Amzoti Fastest editor on MSE.

Comment: yeah my mistake, that was a mistype

Comment: @GitGud: That is only because some of the fastest editors didn't chime in! There are some excellent mathematicians on here and they are great with LaTex and also VERY fast! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me write $Q$ for $x^2+2$. You have $Q^2=x^4+4x^2+4$, but you want $x^4+10x^2+4$, so you need another $6x^2$, which you can get from $6Q$: $$Q^2+6Q=x^4+10x^2+16$$ But you don't want that $16$ at the end, you want $4$, so you subtract $12$: $$Q^2+6Q-12=x^4+10x^2+4$$ That tells you what $f$ is, and lets you answer the question.

Comment: very nice! I did a similar thing, but just say let: $x^2 = x - 2$ and substitute, which gives us $f(x)$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f$ has degree at most $2$, so $f$ can be written as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then, using your knowledge ($(x^2+2)^2=x^4+4x^2+4$) you will easily find the values of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a trick I have found useful,

$$ x^4 + 10x^2 + 4 $$
$$= (x^2)^2 + 10(x^2)+4 $$
$$= \left( (x^2+2)-2 \right)^2 + 10 \left( (x^2+2)-2 \right)+4 $$
$$=(x^2+2)^2-2(x^2+2)(2) +(2)^2 + 10(x^2+2)-10(2)+4 $$
$$= (x^2+2)^2-4(x^2+2) +4+ 10(x^2+2)-20 + 4 $$
$$= (x^2+2)^2 +6(x^2+2)-12 $$

Therefore our polynomial must be $p(u)=u^2+6u-12$.